# Are Runscope Scheduled Tests running sequentially or Parallel?

Tags: testing, web-api-testing, runscope

Here is my situation . We are testing our API with runscope . the main steps are follows .

1. Create an Order by User
2. Driver Take the Order
3. User Cancel the order taken by driver

This process takes around **3** minutes to complete , i want to run a scheduled job for this test every **1** minute .

If scheduled jobs run **parallel** my tests will start and finish like this .

```
test 1  | start at minute 0 |  finish at minute 3
test 2  | start at minute 1 |  finish at minute 4
test 3  | start at minute 2 |  finish at minute 5
test 4  | start at minute 3 |  finish at minute 6
```

so there will be no problem .

But if jobs run **sequential** what will happen is there will be lots of queued jobs in Runscope . because one test will take **3** minutes to complete but we run tests every **1** minute .

so i am afraid that runscope will run out of memory or give an error if the Queue is too large ( Actually i don't know hoe runScope will handle this situation . )

I cannot test this situation because **"Test schedules require a paid Runscope subscription."** , And i don't want to pay without knowing how Runscope will handle the situation .

Please help me to understand how runscope works in this kind of situation .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you using the on-pre agent or a cloud location? The short answer is they run in parallel. We're happy to extend your trial so you can verify the behavior. Email us at help@runscope.com

Comment: @JohnSheehan-Runscope Hi thank you very much for the reply and very sorry for the late reply , we already purchased the paid version now everything is ok . Thanks again :)